# How to store SqlAdapter data into variable?

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

How to access a sql Entity and store into another variable..How do I do it using SqlDataAdapter?

My Query is :

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from Employees where Name = '" + nameTextBox.Text + " ' and Password = '" + passwordTextBox.Text + "'", connection);
```

From where I want to get the EmployeeID which I want to store into another variable ..How do I do it?
Any suggestion please?

Comment: Why did You expect EmployeeID  when You select count?

Comment: `var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("your query");`

Comment: I want to send this EmployeeID to another form ..that's why

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. You're not selecting any EmployeeID, and `SqlDataAdapter` is used for filling a `DataSet`. Perhaps read some basic tutorials on how this stuff works?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on dataAdapter? It is not really for reading data, it is for filling datatables. Use [sqlCommand.executescalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read single pieces of data!